# Spring boot java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a simple spring boot application. I am able to `mvn clean install` and the jar is getting created successfully. But when I try to run `java -jar` or `mvn spring-boot:run` the execution fails with

> "Could not find or load main class
>   com.xyx.webpage.xyx Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.xyx.webpage.xyx"

Please see my pom for more details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xyx</groupId>
<artifactId>webpage</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>webpage</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version>
    <!-- <start-class>com.xyx.webpage.xyx</start-class> -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP, 
        tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>    
            <mainClass>com.xyx.webpage.xyx</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: What would `zipinfo -1 path/to/your.jar | grep HiringApplication` show?

Comment: It is actually not showing anything

Comment: So I unzipped my jar and actually there are no java class files which are getting packaged. Is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: Can you post your other code ?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki can you please suggest

Comment: @jetty Please provide code-snippet of your `HiringApplication` class.

Answer (score 1):

Using this should resolve the issue

In pom.xml, add

```
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.hiringcupid.webpage.HiringApplication</start-class>
        ...
    </properties>
```

Remember, I am using Springboot 2

Answer (score 0):

Please remove below code,

```
<mainClass>com.hiringcupid.webpage.HiringApplication</mainClass>
```

Annotate main class to @SpringBootApplication annotation

Comment: The class is annotated with the @SpringBootApplication. If I dont have start class in properties or maincClass in build plugins the jar creation itself is failing. I am able to run my application from eclipse. The issue is when I am trying to package do java- jar from terminal